# The watcher detects the change and reloads the page without including the change

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, aurelia

This is in the context of running any of these commands:

```
node_modules/.bin/au run --watch --env prod
node_modules/.bin/au run --watch
```

Our `run.ts` has the following.

```
let watch = function() {
  gulp.watch(project.transpiler.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch(project.markupProcessor.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch(project.cssProcessor.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch(project.sassProcessor.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
}
```

The watcher does detect a change in the HTML file and does reload the page. For instance, when we change `src\profile.html` we see the following in the command line window.

```
File Changed: src\profile.html
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processSass'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'buildTypeScript'
Finished 'processSass'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
writeBundlesTracing profile...
Writing app-bundle-5d7004f1cd.js...
Finished 'writeBundles'
Starting 'reload'...
Finished 'reload'
```

**The problem is** that the changes do not appear in the browser window. In other words, Chrome, for instance, will reload the profile page but without showing any changes to the HTML content.

Comment: The use of revisions are _not_ for development environments such as building and watching files. Rather, revisions are for production environments and should be used as such.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is related to setting `aurelia.json` > `build.options.rev` to `true`. There is a related issue in the GitHub repo. A workaround is to set `rev` as follows:

```
"options": {
  "minify": "stage & prod",
  "sourcemaps": "dev & stage",
  "rev": "stage & prod"
},
```

Now when running `au run --watch` in a `dev` environment, the watcher will work, though it still will not when running in a `stage` or `prod` environment.